# How to publish custom action to Facebook from website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-wall, facebook-ui

I successfully published a story from website via Feed and also another approach via sharer.php, but I want something different.

Downside of what I have now is that a picture is small and on the left side. There are no custom verbs as well.

I have seen something like (you can see a screenshot) a bigger photo and custom verbs like '%user got a new highscore at %site', etc.

[Please look at a screenshot here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ubwd4&s=5)

So I want to publish something similar what's shown on above picture. But with different text. 'Got a new highscore on'.

P.S. I want it to be done from website, where user has to log-in via Facebook.